# What are my options for saving GAME-specific Data for my React Native App across Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native, google-play-games

I have a React Native app that integrates with [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/).  It saves Achievement info in particular and I'm looking to use their Quests and Saved Game service as well.

That works fine for Android, but I'm wondering what is available for iOS since I would like have my game be on both device platforms.

In an ideal world I would love a Generic Game service that already has the data modeling like Google Play Services, and not just a generic could db storage.

Comment: Try [Game Center for iOS apps](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/game-center-and-leaderboards-for-your-ios-app--cms-27488) and use [Google Play games for saving games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) on Android.

Comment: This would be my worst-case scenario, needing to integrate with two separate services.  I might not have the time to do both so I would then drop iOS which is a shame.